# Running a Perl script in Eclipse Classic in Linux Redhat

Tags: linux, eclipse, perl, redhat

I have a Perl script which I want to run in Linux. I know about the plugins which we can use, but that's a limitation for me. I will have to use External Tools Configurations to run it. I searched on the internet, but there is no place where i could find the explanation.

I tried using external tools, but when I run it nothing is showing up on my screen. May be I did the wrong way.

The way I filled it was:

- Name: I gave any random name
- Location: I gave /usr/bin/perl
- Working Directory: the path of the directory where my Perl script is located.
- Arguments: Name of my Perl script.

I would also like to mention that my script calls an executable file (a C++ makefile) which runs rest of my program. Maybe that is the problem?

I am using Perl perspective. I am not an Eclipse expert, so I might be missing something important. Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the location would be your Perl script.

1. `/usr/bin/perl /path/to/your/script.pl`
2. `/path/to/your/script.pl`

Check these links, maybe useful:

- http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_add_my_own_external_tools%3F
- http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-exttools-running.htm